# How do you set sea level elevation to white in terrain analysis?

Tags: raster, slope, hillshade, aster, shaded-relief

I have ASTER files I am working with to create a shaded relief background for some other vector shapefiles. In experimenting with different color-elevation options, I am unable to have the Terrain Analysis tool make the surrounding ocean white in color. I have tried manually adding a white color for elevation values 0.0 to 0.0, but no dice. Going to the Table of Contents->Properties and selecting a different color scheme just replaces the Terrain Analysis colors and I have to re-do Terrain Analysis (although that is likely because I don't know how to 'undo' the color change when the 'undo' option is not available). Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some experimentation I have a solution, although it may not be the most efficient one. Go to Table of Contents->Transparency->Custom transparency options. Select a Transparency band from the dropdown menu, and click the plus button to the right of the menu and select a transparency value. Or click the button option to the right of the window, "Add values from display." I then click the ocean sea and set transparency to 100%.

EDIT: However, this process reveals many "pits" in flat areas and fills them white. So my original question stands--any solutions???